Windows terminal cursor sometimes become strange
While using Windows, I frequently encounter the situation provided in the attached image. It looks somewhat auto-completion and the text cursor stands still until I complete typing a word. I think some shortcut that I don't know make this happen, and it drives me so annoyed and everytime I encounter this problem I always reboot my computer. Please help.

What I found today is that it looks messing up the whole Windows text input system.


I found the solution as soon as writing this question. This problem probably applies to Korean users, and the problem was "한글" wordprocessor, "한컴 입력기" technically. Possibly I accidently press Win + Space that switches the input device and that made my Windows to use that weird annoying device.
